# How to distinguish PICTURE OF ME and PICTURE OF MINE in Chinese?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This is a PICTURE OF ME.
>
> This is a PICTURE OF MINE.

Both can be translated to

> 这是我的图片

Answer (score 6, accepted):

这是我的照片 can be interpreted as "It is a photo of me" or "It is a photo that belong to me"

To avoid confusion, you can write:

- 这照片是我的 = "this photo is mine"
- 这照片中的人是我  = "the person in this photo is me"
- 这照片上的人是我  = "the person on this photo is me"

照片 = photo; picture

图片= graphic; picture

Comment: When are things 中 a picture and when are they 上？

Comment: 照片中 = in the picture ; 照片上 = on the picture. You can use either, just like in English

Comment: I'm not aware of any English dialect where "The person *on* this photo" sounds natural.

Comment: When we say 'in a picture'  we are imagining the picture is a world of its own; I was a graphic designer, when I look at a photo, it is natural for me to think a photo is just color patterns on paper.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easist way to distinguish the two is to say:

- 這照片是我的 (mine)
- 這照片是我 (me)

... when you need to say these two phrases in the same conversation.

The second phrase looks odd but it works when you are showing the photo :)

Amother option is adding verb, but that is adding more information which might be unavailable.

- 這照片是我拍的 (I took this photo (implies possition))
- 這照片是我買的 (I bought this photo)

Or adding some prepositons:

- 這照片裡是我 (What is in the picture is me)

Answer (score 0):

It is a unique feature of Chinese, that things like that are hard to distinguish without a context.

“这是我的照片” can be translated into “This is a picture of me” and “This is a picture of mine” depending on the context.

Similar examples are:
中国足球队谁都打不败。
中国乒乓球队谁都打不败。

The exact same structure gives out two completely different meanings, which can only be interpreted correctly in contexts.

Comment: I think the same sentence is also ambiguous in English: *This is my picture*.

Answer (score -1):

search web 英文语法，物主代词 one result http://www.yygrammar.com/Article/201309/3413.html

answering comment:more specific: submit "of mine", "of me" to online dictionaries, e.g. iciba: of mine 我的一个朋友是个非常容易焦虑不安的人 (hence 这是我的一张照片）of me 要看一下我穿过终点线时的照片 吗 ? to emphasize picture shows person, may add person's activity, or location as in quoted example, 这是我穿着囚服的图片（me wearing prison clothes), 这是在监狱里拍摄我的一张相片（picture of me taken in prison)，or submit "picture shows" to iciba: 这张照片照的是女孩的侧面。hence 这张照片照的是我（自己、本人）to specify possession: 这是属于我的一张图片

Comment: Please be more specific to answering the question.